# Clone textview to append it to a ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, view, textview

I have a ViewGroup defined in XML with a view inside, at onCreate time I'd like to have a variable of those.
I don't want to go through the hassle of using a listview+adapter cause its clearly overkill as I know the list won't change since onCreate()
This is more or less the code I'd  like to have.

```
TextView mytextview = myViewGroup.findViewById(R.id.mytext);

for(String test : strings){
  mytextview = mytextview.clone();
  mytextview.setText(test);
  myViewGroup.addView(mytextview);
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What's the current result your getting? The myTextView is only visible once?

Comment: I have added an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15761866/884674 see if it works for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe use an inflater, and put the textview in an external layout file:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.textview_include, null);
viewGroup.addView(v);
```

Comment: what should I do if I can't use an inflater?

Answer (score 2):

Using code of Mathias Lin and using the hint from javahead76:

```
LinearLayout x = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        View c = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.singlerow, x);  
        TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
        t.setId(i+10000);
        t.setText("text"+i);            
    }
    TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(10003);
    b.setText("10003");
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the `findViewById` at the end of the `for` loop? That function returns the `View` for id `0` to `4` (in your case), but your not using that anywhere.

Comment: @ Pimp Trizkit You are right I forgot to remove it. It is old code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this, you will most likely get the exact same id for every view created this way.  This means doing things like `((TextView)v).setText("some text");` will be called on every `TextView` previously inflated from the same layout.  You can still do it this way, but you should call `setId()` and have some reasonable method for ensuring you do not get the same id twice in a row - incrementation or universal time, etc.

Also, I think Android reserves a certain range of id's for dynamically created id's.  You might avoid ID's in this range; but honestly, I don't know the id system works so I could be wrong on this point.