# Set Views from TextViews/Layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view

Is it possible to set the view of a view by taking data from a already created layout?

For example:

I have the layout file **test_layout.XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:text="TextView1"
    android:background="@color/wisteria"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I now want to create a new view that is being created out of this TextView.
If creating a new view out of a Drawable I would simply do:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.shape1);
```

How do I create a new view, by including **all the attributes** in the TextView1? I simply want to create a new view out of a existing TextView. The TextView above acts as a "template". Should I do it by **setViewById**?

I hope I made myself clear, a little hard to describe.

Comment: I believe you want to [clone your view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159211/how-do-i-clone-a-view)?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) and inflate this resource again.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
...
```