# How to reset view to original state after using animators to animates its some properties?

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, viewpropertyanimator

I am using ***animators (ObjectAnimator)*** to animate few properties ***(scale, rotate)*** of a view.

**Target view** is animating properly when ObjectAnimators are set to it.

But there is an added requirement to get view to the **original position** **(reset)** after a while.

I tried to **cancel()** the animator but it only cancels the animation and doesn't reset the view.

**Possible solution :** creating another animator that does just opposite of the initial animator.

Is there any other way to reset it ?

Comment: does it need to reset in the same animation? like fadein-fadeout?

Comment: I have set duration to it. once it is completed I want to reset it to its original unanimated state like it was before animation. 
I need same implementation that occurs with view animation when we have fillEnabled = false.

Comment: try custom interpolator then,  something like CycleInterpolator

Comment: @pskink CycleInterpolator will work in my case with some changes that I need to make with cycles and duration adjustments. Thanks.

Comment: that's why i suggested a custom Interpolator...

Comment: Can you give code sample? How will using CycleInterpolator work except repeating the animation for a specified number of cycles?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, because I animate the view use `ViewPropertyAnimator`, `addView()` and `removeView()` again and again for not creating new view, but a view can be shown once, when you remove the view, you call `addview()` again, it is no show, but you see the property visibility is visible and `animationListener` also be called. it is strange.

Answer (score 1):

See the solution I came up with as I had a similar issue with animations inside views in a recycler view, so I had to find a way to reset them:

[Trying to reset values from Property Animator to be used in recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629326/trying-to-reset-values-from-property-animator-to-be-used-in-recycler-view/45700580#45700580)

Good news in Android O these will be better supported

Answer (score 1):

I had the Same problem with my views . so I came over this problem with this trick .
So We assume we have a view that applying an animate after clicking on it .

```
          viewLayout.arrow_back.setOnClickListener {arrow ->
            arrow.animate().rotationXBy(50F) // this is a just simple anim not so usefull
                .start()
            arrow.isEnabled = false
        }
```

I hope it'll Help someone .

Answer (score 1):

Both `ObjectAnimator.cancel()` and `ObjectAnimator.end()` don't cancel the effects the animation had on the animated object, but rather just cancel its execution at the point in which the methods were called (see [ValueAnimator's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator#cancel()) for more details).

Now, I can think of three main ways to accomplish what you wanted:

1. Put a listener on the `ObjectAnimator`, and when `OnAnimationEnd`/`OnAnimationCancel` is called, manully reset the properties of the view.
2. If the properties of the view you want to reset are those given to it in the XML file, you can re-inflate it. For more details, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900044/clone-textview-to-append-it-to-a-viewgroup).
3. Use the [`ObjectAnimator.reverse()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator#reverse()) method to reverse the execution of the animation, effectively reseting the properties of the view. Preferably, you would want to call start the reverse when the animation ends, so you'd probably need to put a listener on the animator and check  when `OnAnimationEnd` with the animtor to reverse is called.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean stop a running animation? If so, call `clearAnimation()` to remove animations from the views that you called `startAnimation();`
If what you mean is to reset the view to its original appearance after the animation is over, always `setFillAfter(false);` to the animations.

Comment: I mean to reset the view to unanimated position as it was before applying animators. 

clearAnimation() doesn't work. Also it is PropertyAnimation not usual view animations.

Comment: This is the correct solution for resetting an animation. `setFillAfter(false);` did the trick perfectly.